# How to perform a search function in angular 4?

Tags: angular, frontend, web-frontend

As mentioned in the title, i want to perform a `search` function in angular 4. I have the REST Service in the SpringBoot back-End and I have called it in Postman and it works great but in the front-end angular it doesn't.

My code in `Service.TS`

```
@Injectable()
export class EvenementService {

  private evensUrl_del = 'http://localhost:8080/evenement';
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Get all events
  getEvenement(): Promise<Evenement[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.evensUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Evenement[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getEvenementByType(typeE: string): Promise<Evenement[]> {
return this.http.get(this.evensUrl_del + '/evenements/' + typeE, this.options)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json() as Evenement)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}
    }

My `Component.TS`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-evenement',
  templateUrl: './evenement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./evenement.component.css']
})
export class EvenementComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Evenement = new Evenement();
  evenmt: Evenement[];
  //e: Evenement[];

  typeE: string;

  constructor(public router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal, private evenementService: EvenementService, private toastyService: ToastyService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.typeE="";
    //this.getEvenements();
  }

  ver(events: Evenement, modal) {
    evenmt => this.evenmt = evenmt;
    this.modalService.open(modal, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  searchEvenement(){
    this.evenementService.getEvenementByType(this.typeE).then(evenmt => this.evenmt = evenmt);
  }

  getEvenements() {
    this.evenementService.getEvenement().then(evenmt => this.evenmt = evenmt);
  }
}
```

Finally the `component.html`

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="typeE"><b>Type</b></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeE" name="typeE" [(ngModel)]="typeE" required>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="searchEvenement()">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let e of evenmt">
            <h4>{{e.typeE}} - {{e.prixE}} {{e.dateE}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

With the code above, when I hit the **Search** button in the browser, it returns the following error:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 302 OK for URL: http://localhost:8080/evenement/evenements/degustation** despite the fact that in eclipse terminal, the line i look for is displayed. So I think that the problem is actually in Angular but I don't know where excatly.

Can somebody help me to figure this out? Thanks

Comment: First, I recommend to use Observable! You can try with HttpClient, like that:
return this._http.get<any>(`http://localhost:8080/evenement/evenements/${typeE}`);
Try and tell me if worked!

Comment: Thanks @Chiien but it still doesn't work. same error.

Comment: Really? Sorry =(! You tried with Chrome dev tools? If typeE data is passing? is sending the data?

Comment: sorry for the late I have internet issues... excuse me but what do you mean by **Chrome Dev tools**?

Comment: Relax! Well, what I want to know, if request is working, you can use Dev Tools, F12 network to see if is send correctly all data!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for promise you can modify code as:

**service**

```
@Injectable()
export class EvenementService {

    private evensUrl_del = 'http://localhost:8080/evenement';
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    // Get all events
    getEvenement(): Promise<Evenement[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.evensUrl)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
    }

    getEvenementByType(typeE: string): Promise<Evenement[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.evensUrl_del}/evenements/${typeE}`, this.options)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
    } 
}
```

**component**

```
searchEvenement(){
    this.evenementService.getEvenementByType(this.typeE).subscribe(evenmt => {
        setTimeout(() => { <====== You can use timeout
            this.evenmt = evenmt;
        });
    });
}

getEvenements() {
    this.evenementService.getEvenement().subscribe(evenmt => this.evenmt = evenmt);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late I have internet connection issues... Thanks for your solution but still it is the same error. With your solution, in the console, it returns the field I've searched but it doesn't display it on the view.

Comment: @BaNRoOt in console you are getting means you are getting filtered data in console, right?

Comment: @BaNRoOt can you add `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`? So method definition would be: `searchEvenement(){
    this.evenementService.getEvenementByType(this.typeE).subscribe(evenmt => {
     this.evenmt = evenmt; ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
     });
}

`

Comment: yes @Anshuman Jaiswal this is what i mean. wait i will post an image of  the whole thing...

Comment: Sorry @Anshuman Jaiswal but it's the same error...still doesn't work

Comment: @BaNRoOt can you try by adding `this.zone.run(() => {this.evenmt = evenmt;});` at the place of `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: @BaNRoOt you will have to add `private zone:NgZone` in `constructor`

Comment: @BaNRoOt if it still doesn't work I updated my answer by using `setTimeout`, that should work.